# What is the best way to apply more than one CompletableFuture on result of another CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, completable-future

Lets make up an example:
We have four methods:

```
CompletableFututre<Void> loadAndApply(SomeObject someObject);
CompletableFuture<SomeData> loadData();
A processA(SomeData data);
B processB(SomeData data);
```

`loadAndApply` combines all other methods. `loadData` gets data for a long time. Then we set `someObject.A` to result of running `processA(data)` and set `someObject.B` to result of running `processB(data)` 
We can't apply both `processA` and `processB` at the same time because `processA` can only be run on `swingExecutor` and `processB` can be run only on `backgroundExecutor`.

So my question here is: can we somehow chain all these methods in some good looking way?

Currently I launch them like this:

```
CompletableFututre<Void> loadAndApply(SomeObject someObject) {
    return loadData()
      .thenApplyAsync(data -> { someObject.setA(processA(data)); return data; }, swingExecutor)
      .thenAcceptAsync(data -> someObject.setB(processB(data)), backgroundExecutor);
}
```

is there any way looking better than `applyAsync` that actually does not apply anything on given object and just returns it for the next future?

Comment: Not sure to understand your question correctly but couldn't you just store the future from `loadData()` in a local variable, and call `thenAcceptAsync()` on it twice?

Comment: @DidierL yes, it's one of the options, but I am looking for some way to do by calling methods one by one(sort of oneliner) without any helper variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using [`CompletionStage.thenCompose(Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenCompose(java.util.function.Function)) in combination with [`CompletableFuture.allOf(CompletableFuture...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf(java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...)). The generic signature of the `Function` used by `thenCompose` is: `Function<? super T, ? extends CompletionStage<U>>`.

```
public CompletableFuture<Void> loadAndApply(SomeObject object) {
  return loadData().thenCompose(data ->
      CompletableFuture.allOf(
          CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> object.setA(processA(data)), swingExecutor),
          CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> object.setB(processB(data)), backgroundExecutor)
      ) // End of "allOf"
  ); // End of "thenCompose"
} // End of "loadAndApply"
```

This has an added benefit. In the code your are currently using the `thenAcceptAsync` stage has to wait for the `thenApplyAsync` stage to complete before it can execute. When using the above both `setA` and `setB` will run concurrently in their respective executors.

For the sake of convenience, here's Javadoc for `allOf`:

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is completed when all of the
>   given CompletableFutures complete. If any of the given
>   CompletableFutures complete exceptionally, then the returned
>   CompletableFuture also does so, with a CompletionException holding
>   this exception as its cause. Otherwise, the results, if any, of the
>   given CompletableFutures are not reflected in the returned
>   CompletableFuture, but may be obtained by inspecting them
>   individually. If no CompletableFutures are provided, returns a
>   CompletableFuture completed with the value null.
>
> Among the applications of this method is to await completion of a set
>   of independent CompletableFutures before continuing a program, as in:
>   CompletableFuture.allOf(c1, c2, c3).join();.

...and the Javadoc for `thenCompose`:

> Returns a new CompletionStage that is completed with the same value as
>   the CompletionStage returned by the given function.
>
> When this stage completes normally, the given function is invoked with
>   this stage's result as the argument, returning another
>   CompletionStage. When that stage completes normally, the
>   CompletionStage returned by this method is completed with the same
>   value.
>
> To ensure progress, the supplied function must arrange eventual
>   completion of its result.
>
> This method is analogous to Optional.flatMap and Stream.flatMap.
>
> See the CompletionStage documentation for rules covering exceptional
>   completion.

*Note: `CompletableFuture`, which implements `CompletionStage`, overrides `thenCompose` but makes the return type more specific (returns `CompletableFuture` rather than `CompletionStage`)*.